# Does "polemic" always have a negative connotation?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, connotations

I have seen a political discussion on live tv in germany. After attacking a member of the discussion made some solid arguments the attacked person responded by saying what he is saying is pure polemic.

So let me specify my question:

Are there situation where polemic can be negative and positive connotated?

And has the connotation changed in one direction more than in another one (maybe in the last years)?

Comment: I think what the accuser was trying to say is that the person was aiding and/or abetting controversy. Is something controversial necessarily _negative_ (with respect to what, that is)? In this context it would be, I suppose, but generally it need not be.

Comment: @user2684291 Ty, I think your intepration of what the accuser was trying to articulate is correct. But I can't think of a positive connotation in a discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A [polemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polemic)

is someone who aggressively argues their point of view and is purposely contentious.

> "[The word is derived from the Greek meaning warlike, hostile.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polemic)"

In and of itself, polemic is neither positive nor negative, however, since the view may seem radically different to society *at the time*, it is usually thought to be negative since it goes against the *status quo*.

However, over time, the view may become appreciated, accepted, and main stream.

An example of this is Martin Luther's [Ninety-five Theses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninety-five_Theses) which at the time was considered heresy and resulted in his ex-communication from the Catholic Church and being declared an outlaw.  The ultimate result has been all the Protestant denominations of Christian faith and a vernacular Bible.

Was Luther a thorn in the side of the Catholic Church?  Yes.
Is he now considered a great man? Yes.
Is his soul burning in hell?  Probably not.

Comment: good example, ty